# ThreadAbortException in ASP.NET + SQLite

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, system.data.sqlite

I am facing this problem a while. Sometimes (just sometimes) i am getting ThreadAbortException in Page_PreRender of one my aspx pages.
this is so odd, i get it sometimes in somedays. I am using SQLite with NHibernate in an asp.net website hosting in a shared webhost.
The exception is :

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Step(SQLiteStatement stmt)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader.NextResult()
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataReader..ctor(SQLiteCommand cmd, CommandBehavior behave)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.NonBatchingBatcher.AddToBatch(IExpectation expectation)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.UpdateOrInsert(Object id, Object[] fields, Object[] oldFields, Object rowId, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j, Object oldVersion, Object obj, SqlCommandInfo sql, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.Update(Object id, Object[] fields, Int32[] dirtyFields, Boolean hasDirtyCollection, Object[] oldFields, Object oldVersion, Object obj, Object rowId, ISessionImplementor session)
   at NHibernate.Action.EntityUpdateAction.Execute()
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.Execute(IExecutable executable)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions(IList list)
   at NHibernate.Engine.ActionQueue.ExecuteActions()
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.AbstractFlushingEventListener.PerformExecutions(IEventSource session)
   at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultFlushEventListener.OnFlush(FlushEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Flush()
```

do you have any idea ??

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your code took too long to execute (because of too much data, or because SQLite is waiting for another thread's lock on the database).
Try increasing `httpRuntime`'s `executionTimeout` in the `web.config`.

Comment: SQLite waiting for another thread is possible, how can i fix this issue ?

Comment: By not doing writes when other threads access the DB at the same time. Or use another database with better concurrency.

Comment: can i use some thread-sync technique to pause writes until other threads release db ? and do you know any other database light as sqlite ?

Comment: Something like `ReaderWriterLock`(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx). Use any database offered by your webhoster.

Comment: Thanks, I ran a test to multiple insert for more than 500 simultaneous thread in my local PC. It worked fine without any error. so i assume that write is not my problem. I think maybe something on the server Aborting the threads (something like antivirus or firewall or any third party program). Is there any way i can find out who is requesting thread.abort ? I mean Who wants this thread aborted ?

Comment: The web server, to prevent overloading the shared server.

Comment: I fount out that i am using some payment webservices in these points of code. Calling a webservice can be cause of this kind of exception ?